How to Use React Helmet Async to Manage Meta Tags for Social Media Sharing in a Single Page React App?
I'm working on a single page application (SPA) using React, and I need to manage meta tags for better social media sharing (like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.). I've heard that react-helmet-async is a good library for this purpose, but I'm having trouble setting it up correctly.
Here's what I want to achieve:
Dynamically update meta tags for each route in my SPA.
Ensure that social media platforms can extract the correct meta information when sharing links to my site.
I've installed react-helmet and followed some tutorials, but I can't seem to get the meta tags to be previewed on social handles. Here's a simplified version of my code:
import CommunityTemplate from "@/app/components/community/CommunityTemplate";
import CommunityProvider from "@/app/context/community/CommunityProvider";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";

export default function Community() {
  return (
    <CommunityProvider>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Home || EcoTable</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="ecotable,food-ecosystem" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="EcoTable is an innovative online community that brings together individuals and businesses passionate about building a more sustainable food ecosystem. Whether you're a home chef, restaurant owner, farmer, or simply someone who cares about food-related issues, EcoTable provides a vibrant platform to share, learn, and connect."
        />
        <meta property="og:title" content={"Home || EcoTable"} />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="EcoTable is an innovative online community that brings together individuals and businesses passionate about building a more sustainable food ecosystem. Whether you're a home chef, restaurant owner, farmer, or simply someone who cares about food-related issues, EcoTable provides a vibrant platform to share, learn, and connect."
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content={"https://www.ecotable.app/assets/LOGO---3AERcc.jpg"}
        />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="Home - EcoTable" />
        <meta
          name="twitter:description"
          content="EcoTable is an innovative online community that brings together individuals and businesses passionate about building a more sustainable food ecosystem. Whether you're a home chef, restaurant owner, farmer, or simply someone who cares about food-related issues, EcoTable provides a vibrant platform to share, learn, and connect."
        />
        <meta
          name="twitter:image"
          content="https://www.ecotable.app/assets/LOGO---3AERcc.jpg"
        />
      </Helmet>

      <CommunityTemplate />
    </CommunityProvider>
  );
}

